# How to handle error when migrating code from javascript to typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling

I am building a project in node. I am trying to migrate my code from javascript to typescript.

Javascript error handling:

```
try{

 //some code ...........
 
}catch(err){

  err.status= 500;
  throw err;

}
```

Now when I tried to migrate to typescript I got following error `err: unknown,  Object is of type unknown`.

So i change my logic to this:

```
try {

    //Some code ..............

} catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
        err.status = 500;
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Now I get error as `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'`.

Please guide me on how to migrate my error logic from `js` to `ts`.

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript, instance of an `Error` contains only `name`, `message`, and `stack` properties.

```js
interface Error {
  name: string;
  message: string;
  stack?: string;
}
```

You're seeing `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'` because `Error` does not have a `status` property.

I suggest you find the class that the error belongs to and do something like the below:

```js
try {
  // Some code ...
} catch (err) {
  //  Assuming `MyErrorClass` has a `status` property or a getter.
  if (err instanceof MyErrorClass) {
    err.status = 500;
    throw err;
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

You also need to note that not all errors are instances of some error class. Someone could just write,

```js
type MyErrorType = {
  message: string,
  status: number,
}

function throwMe() {
  const error:MyErrorType = { 
    message: 'Damn! this is just a string thrown as an error',
    status: 200,
  };
  throw error;
}

try {
  throwMe();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error instanceof Error); // Will print -> false
}
```

In that case, if you know the type, you can do a cast like the below:

```js
try {
  // Some code ...
} catch (err) {
  (err as MyErrorType).status = 500;
  throw err;
}
```